# password protect directory with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Hi I am trying to password protect a directory with .htaccess.
I have created a .htpasswd file and stored it at the root of the server.
I have created a .htaccess file in the directory I want to protect with the following lines:

```
AuthUserFile /home/baltzers/domains/baltzersciencepublishers.com/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
require user test
```

But when I fill in my username and (encrypted) password, it keeps throwing back up the authentication dialog.
What am I missing?

Comment: What happens if you use the unencrypted password?

Comment: Does that .htpasswd file actually exist? Did you use htpasswd to generate its contents?

Comment: I just created a .htpasswd file with my text editor. Don't have shell access.

Comment: Ahhh, how could I have missed that, it worked. Thanks!

Comment: okay, but you're sure it's in the right format? that is
user1:encryptedpass1[enter]user2:encryptedpass2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mught want to replace the line `require user test` with:

```
require valid-user
```

Otherwise, the user must be named "test" and exist in the `.htpasswd` file.

Comment: I did change that now, and when I fill in the proper creds I get:Authorization Required

This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/password/

The tool will create the files you need based on your form input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the unencrypted password when logging in. Note that unless you're doing the whole chain encrypted (i.e. you're using `https` instead of `http`) then the username and password will be sent in the clear.