# Was my htaccess hacked?

Tags: .htaccess

I found these following lines in my `.htaccess` file..  I've replaced my website name with `example.com`.   I didn't add this to my `.htaccess` file...

```
AuthName "example.com"
AuthUserFile "/home3/examplec1/.htpasswds/public_html/example.com/passwd"
```

What is this and why was it added to my `.htaccess` file?  Is it possible someone has downloaded the public_html file?

If i did get hacked, how do i prevent from getting hacked again?

I did try to protect a folder(can't remember which one) previously in cpanel, would this alter my `.htaccess`?

Comment: Perhaps you should mention which OS you are using.

Comment: My guess is your host did some updates

Comment: That is an incomplete directory protection which is meant for password protecting directories like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424752/password-protect-directory-with-htaccess?rq=1 and should cause you no harm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably was added by your hosting provider or by someone who also has access to your environment. Adding a protection cannot seriously harm you. Removing or changing a protection would be worse.