# Secure area / .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to have a secure area / login on our website for staff to access files, mainly company policies so pretty basic.

I've created a folder (outside the public_html) in the main directory, Called 'Staff' with a .htaccess file in it. I can't work out how to link to a .html page in this directory from another page however. Help please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [password protect directory with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424752/password-protect-directory-with-htaccess)

Comment: All the content that you want to expose to the outside should be in the public directory for simplicity. Inside the public folder create the _Staff_ folder and inside it add a `.htaccess` file to restrict access to it.

Comment: An alternative to what @FranciscoHanna suggests is to use the `Alias` directive which allows to "map" physical locations inside the server side file system into the virtual file system exposed via the http server.